# FFMPEG warning pkt->duration = 0

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, hls

I'm facing a strange WARNING message in the logs of FFMPEG when trying to capture an HLS stream.

This is the log with some information changed to avoid problems with my boss:

```
[info] Input #0, hls, from 'https://cdn.youtube.com/w/application/stream_key/playlist.m3u8':
[info]   Duration: N/A, start: 421.372522, bitrate: N/A
[info]   Program 0
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       variant_bitrate : 3534714
[info]     Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449), 0/1
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       variant_bitrate : 3534714

[info]     Stream #0:1, 21, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1280x720, 0/1, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       variant_bitrate : 3534714
[info]     Stream #0:2, 33, 1/90000: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       variant_bitrate : 3534714
[debug] Successfully opened the file.
[debug] Parsing a group of options: output url application/stream_key/playlist.m3u8.
[debug] Applying option c (codec name) with argument copy.
[debug] Applying option f (force format) with argument hls.
[debug] Successfully parsed a group of options.
[debug] Opening an output file: application/stream_key/playlist.m3u8.

[debug] Successfully opened the file.

[mpegts @ 0x400b000] [verbose] service 1 using PCR in pid=256, pcr_period=0ms
[mpegts @ 0x400b000] [verbose] muxrate VBR, sdt every 1073741822000 ms, pat/pmt every 1073741822000 ms
[file @ 0x3fc0040] [debug] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[hls muxer @ 0x4049e40] [debug] Found playlist sequence number: 0
[AVIOContext @ 0x4107900] [verbose] Statistics: 132 bytes read, 0 seeks
[info] Output #0, hls, to 'application/stream_key/playlist.m3u8':
[info]   Metadata:
[info]     encoder         : Lavf58.65.100

[info]     Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1280x720 (0x0), 0/1, q=2-31, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       variant_bitrate : 3534714
[info]     Stream #0:1, 0, 1/90000: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
[info]     Metadata:
[info]       variant_bitrate : 3534714
[info] Stream mapping:
[info]   Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
[info]   Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
[info] Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[debug] cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[debug] cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[debug] cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[debug] cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[debug] cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[hls @ 0x4076e00]
[warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise

[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
[hls @ 0x4076e00] [warning] pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise
```

### FFMPEG command used:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel repeat+level+debug -y \
-xerror -i cdn.youtube.com/w/application/stream_key/playlist.m3u8 \
-c copy -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename \
application/stream_key/chunck_list_JMV%d.ts -hls_flags \
append_list application/stream_key/playlist.m3u8
```

### FFMPEG version

```
ffmpeg -version 
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 
Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 
libavformat 58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100 libavdevice 58. 8.100 / 58. 8.100 libavfilter 7. 57.100 / 7. 57.100 libavresample 4. 0. 0 / 4. 0. 0 libswscale 5. 5.100 / 5. 5.100 libswresample 3. 5.100 / 3. 5.100 libpostproc 55. 5.100 / 55. 5.100
```

I want to know what this *pkt->duration = 0* means. Is it a problem in the output or the input?

Since now, thanks.

- If you need more info please write it down and I'll try to provide it.

Comment: Does the output look OK? Unable to provide any suggestions without your command and the **complete** log (you may omit stream key).

Comment: I don't really know if the output is ok because the program manager kills the FFMPEG process when a warning or error is detected. I want to know what that warning means.

Comment: The command used was ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel repeat+level+debug -y -xerror -i https://cdn.youtube.com/w/application/stream_key/playlist.m3u8 -c copy -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename application/stream_key/chunck_list_JMV%d.ts -hls_flags append_list application/stream_key/playlist.m3u8

Comment: ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to send the comment configured to enhance the readability

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add the info.

Comment: Alright, I was trying to edit the comment but it seems to not be possible. So I'll update the question as you said @llogan

Comment: Now the question is updated!

Comment: I had the *`pkt->duration = 0`* warning too when using *ffmpeg* as provided by the apt `ffmpeg` package provided for *Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Raspberry Pi edition*  (jammy) (`ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers`). ... The issue gets resolved (i.e., no such warnings anymore) when I use a more recent *ffmpeg* version, built from the current (as of this writing) `master` codebase (`ffmpeg version N-113626-g106527d2e5 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers`).